# Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, drop-down-menu

I can't get rid of this error and my file is forever red.

I've tried adding types to useRef(null) but I can't get rid of the error. Maybe I'm adding the wrong types?

```
const dropdownRef = useRef(null);

const closeOpenMenus = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log((dropdownRef.current))
        if (((dropdownRef.current) && (!dropdownRef.current.contains(e.target))) && (e.target !== buttonRef.current)) {
            setDropHide(
                {
                    ishidden: true,
                    icon: "line-md:chevron-small-right"
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: `useRef<HTMLElement>(null)`

Comment: When I add this I get Argument of type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node | null'. on e.target. and then Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'. on the ref={dropdownRef} inside div. I feel like I keep moving the errors around.

Comment: `useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)`

Comment: Oh my I love you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would aproach this code:

```
const dropdownRef = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);

const closeOpenMenus = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log((dropdownRef.current))
        if (((dropdownRef.current) && (!dropdownRef.current.contains(e.target as Node))) && (e.target !== buttonRef.current)) {
            setDropHide(
                {
                    ishidden: true,
                    icon: "line-md:chevron-small-right"
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I see the "as Node" and the <type | null>, but why?